# Comparing two columns in a data frame across many rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I'm working with in which I'd like to compare a data point `Genotype` with two references `S288C` and `SK1`. This comparison will be done across many rows (100+) of the data frame. Here are the first few lines of my data frame:

```
    Assay   Genotype S288C SK1
1   CCT6-002     G     A    G
2   CCT6-007     G     A    G
3   CCT6-013     C     T    C
4   CCT6-015     G     A    G
5   CCT6-016     G     G    T
```

As a final product, I'd like a character string of 1's (`S288C`) and 0's (`SK1`) depending on which of the references the data point matches. Thus in the example above I'd like an output of `00001` since all except the last match `SK1`.

Comment: What are you comparing, and how is the comparison to be made?  Give us some sample output that goes along with your sample input.

Comment: I am comparing Genotype to each of the next two columns S288C and SK1.  When Genotype is identical to S288C id like to output a "1" and when its identical to SK1, id like to output a "0". If it matches neither "NA". Id like this comparison to happen at each row. Does this help?

Comment: The 7,000th R question?!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A nested `ifelse` should do it (take a look at `help(ifelse)` for usage):

```
ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$S288C,1,ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$SK1,0,NA))
```

With this test data:

```
> dat
     Genotype S288C SK1
[1,] "G"      "A"   "G"
[2,] "G"      "A"   "G"
[3,] "C"      "T"   "C"
[4,] "G"      "A"   "G"
[5,] "G"      "G"   "T"
[6,] "G"      "A"   "A"
```

We get:

```
> ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$S288C,1,ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$SK1,0,NA))
[1]  0  0  0  0  1 NA
```

(**Note:**  If you have trouble using this, you'll want to make sure that the columns are vectors, and are not treated by R as factors...a simple for loop should do it:  `for (i in 1:ncol(dat)){dat[,i]=as.vector(dat[,i])}`).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! If I wanted to add the results as a new column to the data frame (ie after the SK1 column) how would I do so? Sorry if this is basic but im very new to R and programming in general.

Comment: The `cbind` function should work:  `newdat<-as.data.frame(cbind(dat,ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$S288C,1,ifelse(dat$Genotype==dat$SK1,0,NA))))`.

Comment: when i run the above cbind function, it gives me back what looks like a 2 part data frame. The first part is the original data frame, the second is the calls made using the above language with the corresponding line number. Is there a way to get these all to align within the same data frame?