# Compare group of two columns and return index matches R

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

Many thanks for reading. Apologies for what I'm sure is a simple task.

I have a dataframe:
(Edited: Added extra column not to be included in comparison)

```
b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11) 
c = c('david','alan','pete', 'ben', 'richard', 'edd') 
d = c('alex','edd','ben','pete','raymond', 'alan')
df = data.frame(b, c, d) 
df
   b       c       d
1  5   david    alex
2  6    alan     edd
3  7    pete     ben
4  8     ben    pete
5 10 richard raymond
6 11     edd    alan
```

I want to compare the group of columns `c` and `d` with the group of columns `d` and `c`. That is, for one row, I want to compare the combined values in `c` and `d` with the combined values in `d` and `c` for all other rows.

(Note the values could either be characters or integers)

Where these match I want to return the index of those rows which match, preferably as a list of lists. I need to be able to access the indexes without referring to the values in column `c` or `d`.

I.e. for the above dataframe, my expected output would be:

```
c(c(2, 6), c(3, 4))
((2,6), (3,4))
```

As:

```
Row 2: (c + d == alan + edd) = row 6: (d + c == edd + alan)
Row 3: (c + d == pete + ben) = row 4: (d + c == ben + pete)
```

I understand how to determine the match case for two separate columns using `match` `melt`, but not if they are joined together and iterating over all possible row combinations.

I envision something like:

```
lapply(1:6, function(x), ifelse((df$a & df$b) == (df$b & df$a), index(x), 0))
```

But obviously that is incorrect and won't work.

I consulted the following questions but have been unable to formulate an answer. I have no idea where to begin.

[Matching multiple columns on different data frames and getting other column as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286881/matching-multiple-columns-on-different-data-frames-and-getting-other-column-as-r)

[match two columns with two other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880450/match-two-columns-with-two-other-columns)

[Comparing two columns in a data frame across many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653141/comparing-two-columns-in-a-data-frame-across-many-rows)

[R Comparing each value of all pairs of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372383/r-comparing-each-value-of-all-pairs-of-columns)

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this.  It splits the row indices `1:nrow(df)` according to unique sorted strings formed from the columns of df.  The sorting ensures that `A,B` and `B,A` are treated identically.

```
duplist <- split(1:nrow(df),apply(df,1,function(r) paste(sort(r),collapse=" ")))

duplist
$`alan edd`
[1] 2 6

$`alex david`
[1] 1

$`ben pete`
[1] 3 4

$`raymond richard`
[1] 5
```

Comment: How to specify column names? I.e. if have 2 other columns with different names?

Comment: This will work with any number of columns, provided df consists only of the columns of names.  The names of the columns do not matter.  Or you could just substitute `df[,c("e","f")]` for `df` if you only want to compare a particular pair of columns.

Comment: Ideally I would like to keep only those pairs which have matches, not when only 1 row is returned. Is it possible to auto remove elements with length 1?

Comment: In addition, how to access all of the numbers without referring to the individual list names? (By the way, thank you so much for the answer - it's like 95% of what I need and way ahead of anything I could have put together. Really appreciate the help)

Comment: Use `duplist <- duplist[sapply(duplist,length)>1]` to just keep those with more than one match.  You can also refer to the list elements by number, so `duplist[[1]]` is `2 6`.  Also `names(duplist[1])` (note the single []) would be `"alan edd"`.

Comment: Thank you. This will work. I really appreciate your answer and your help. Have a nice day :)