# Compare multiple columns in 2 different dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, compare

I am trying to compare multiple columns in two different dataframes in R. This has been addressed previously on the forum ([Compare group of two columns and return index matches R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132862/compare-group-of-two-columns-and-return-index-matches-r)) but this is a different scenario: I am trying to compare if a column in `dataframe 1` is between the range of 2 columns in `dataframe 2`. Functions like `match, merge, join, intersect` won't work here. I have been trying to use `purr::pluck` but didn't get far. The dataframes are of different sizes.

> Below is an example:

```
temp1.df <- mtcars

temp2.df <- data.frame(
  Cyl = sample (4:8, 100, replace = TRUE),
  Start = sample (1:22, 100, replace = TRUE),
  End = sample (1:22, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

temp1.df$cyl <- as.character(temp1.df$cyl)
temp2.df$Cyl <- as.character(temp2.df$Cyl)
```

> My attempt:

```
temp1.df <- temp1.df %>% mutate (new_mpg = case_when (
  temp1.df$cyl %in% temp2.df$Cyl & temp2.df$Start <= temp1.df$mpg & temp2.df$End >= temp1.df$mpg ~ 1
))
```

> Error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `new_mpg` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 100
```

> Expected Result:
>
> 1. Compare temp1.df$cyl and temp2.df$Cyl. If they are match then -->
> 2. Check if temp1.df$mpg is between temp2.df$Start and temp2.df$End -->
> 3. if it is, then create a new variable new_mpg with value of 1.

It's hard to show the exact expected output here.

I realize I could loop this so for each row of `temp1.df` but the original `temp2.df` has over 250,000 rows. An efficient solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp1.df$new_mpg<-apply(temp1.df, 1, function(x) {
  temp<-temp2.df[temp2.df$Cyl==x[2],] 
  ifelse(any(apply(temp, 1, function(y) {
    dplyr::between(as.numeric(x[1]),as.numeric(y[2]),as.numeric(y[3]))
  })),1,0)
})
```

Note that this makes some assumptions about the organization of your actual data (in particular, I can't call on the column names within `apply`, so I'm using indexes - which may very well change, so you might want to rearrange your data between receiving it and calling `apply`, or maybe changing the organization of it within `apply`, e.g., by `apply(temp1.df[,c("mpg","cyl")]...`.

At any rate, this breaks your data set into lines, and each line is compared to the a subset of the second dataset with the same Cyl count. Within this subset, it checks if `any` of the mpg for this line falls `between` (from `dplyr`) `Start` and `End`, and returns 1 if yes (or 0 if no). All these ones and zeros are then returned as a (named) vector, which can be placed into `temp1.df$new_mpg`.

I'm guessing there's a way to do this with `rowwise`, but I could never get it to work properly...

Comment: The solution works when `cyl` and `Cyl` are `numeric`. I overlooked that my `cyl` and `Cyl` in the original dataset are characters. If so the above solution does not work. Gives ` Error in dplyr::between(x[1], y[2], y[3]) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double]. `

Comment: Here's the code with column names. `temp1.df$cyl <- as.character(temp1.df$cyl)
temp2.df$Cyl <- as.character(temp2.df$Cyl)
temp1.df$mpg <- as.numeric(temp1.df$mpg)
temp2.df$Start <- as.numeric(temp2.df$Start)
temp2.df$End <- as.numeric(temp2.df$End)

temp1.df$new_mpg<-apply(temp1.df [,c("mpg", "cyl")], 1, function(x) {
  temp<-temp2.df[temp2.df$Cyl==x["cyl"],] 
  print (temp)
  ifelse(any(apply(temp, 1, function(y) {
    dplyr::between(x["mpg"],y["Start"],y["End"])
  })),1,0)
})`

Comment: Just add `as.numeric()` to each of the arguments in `between`. I've adjusted the code above.

Comment: For a datasets with 1101 and 256833 observations it takes a while but it works great. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it's an apply within an apply - not surprised it's taking a while... Glad it works for you nevertheless.